# Can I recover the WhatsApp chat history from a damaged phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, physical-damage

My phone has suffered physical damage and it will no longer turn on. I have given it to a phone repair shop in the hope that the data is still alive in there and that it can be extracted using external means. Assuming I can get a copy of the internal storage of that phone into a thumb drive, one of the things I would like to recover from it is the WhatsApp chat history. The [standard procedure](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74973/transfer-whatsapp-chat-history-to-new-device), however, requires a working Android system on the old phone to work, and this might be a little too much of a stretch given the damage.

Is there a way to recover the chat history given these circumstances? Or is it lost to history due to WhatsApp's encryption mechanisms?

Comment: If you made a backup previously, it's a maybe, and that's still a big maybe. Without one, the chances are low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you can save **everything** in the `/data/data/com.whatsapp` folder. Your logs will be in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` but they are encrypted as you mentioned and encryption key is in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key`. Proper transfer of these files will mean a successful operation. Once you start Whatsapp on another phone with the `/data` folder from your broken phone and start Whatsapp, it will prompt you to activate Whatsapp on this phone with a text like *"This account wasn't activated on this phone, please activate"* and once you do, it'll be successfully done.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still waiting for the workshop to come back and say whether they recovered the data; if they did I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I was unable to recover the data so I don't know for sure that this works, but it sounds about right so I'm accepting this.