# Restore whatsapp Backup in unexpected hidden/inaccessible location

Tags: rooting, whatsapp-messenger, restore, hidden

**Device**: Samsung Galaxy XCover Pro

**OS**: Android 12

I need to restore a (local) backup of Whatsapp. Contrary to what [Whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/601558080647471/?locale=en_US) sais, it is *not* stored in:

`/sdcard/Whatsapp/Databases`

nor in

`/internal storage/Whatsapp/Databases`

Rather, the backups are in:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Databases`

The files can be found by the "My Files (v13.1.01.321)" app, when searching for them. But I can't copy, move or rename them, as indicated by the whatsapp FAQ (see above link). Also, navigating to the files is impossible, as the `Databases` directory seems to be hidden/inexistent. (Tried with "My Files" app, Nautilus file manager on GNU/Linux Laptop and adb shell)

So, how do I restore the back up now? Do I have to "root" the phone?

Thank you very much.

Comment: FAQ: [WhatsApp doesn't prompt to restore from local storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325). It should be possible to access those files without root since those are public files. Make sure the app has "Allow management of all files" permission instead of "Allow access to media only". Based on personal testing, [Files by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) is able to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't answer yet, since I deleted the data when uninstalling whatsapp. Trying to recover but not hopeful -_-