# Merging WhatsApp chat histories from different devices but same account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat-history

Is it possible to merge WhatsApp chat histories on 2 Android devices (but 1 account)?

If so, how?

Comment: There is a [comprehensive and somewhat involved procedure on quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-restore-multiple-backups-of-whatsapp-chats). I'll update this answer once I've tried it.

Answer (score 3):

Admission: This doesn't fully answer your question, but it may help others struggling like I was with chat-history transfer. I couldn't better place my tip elsewhere ([like here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62237/how-to-transfer-whatsapp-conversations-to-a-new-phone)) because I don't have the reputation yet to allow me to do so.

Today I finally (read, much hair pulled over last few days) moved from my old Samsung S4 to a Note Edge (Note 4) with the same phone number. The [directions](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20902622) WhatsApp gives for transferring history is incomplete or out-of-date it seems. In my case the last crucial step was to RENAME the **msgstore.db.crypt8** file to **msgstore.db.crypt**. Bingo! This time when installing and activating WhatsApp the missing "Restore" question came up, and all went fine. HTH

Credit: crucial tip discovered in [another response here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52684/fail-in-restoring-whatsapp-chats?lq=1) at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The most realistic approach I've found is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsapp/comments/519udo/how_to_merge_whatsapp_databases/d7d2gdg?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

1. [decrypt](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2689911) the WhatsApp backup file with the WhatCrypt app
2. merge two sql databases.
3. encrypt it

---

Although the approach looks promising, WhatCrypt 2.4 failed for me. (This is the most recent version for October 2019 - no updates since October 2016. It's still available via the Wayback machine.). I get "Different key file for this database". But maybe I'm simply doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried this few times first time I tried it long ago I got successful merge 2 `msgstore.db i.e. unencrypted ` files but it gave me `malformed database` error and attempted to restore from backup to `/data / data / com.whatsapp /` second time I tried it WhatsApp versions were different. one was latest version and when I tried to run update, 2 update records I got `constraint violation error ` if you had any luck let me know what workeds for you