# Can I transfer WhatsApp messages from Iphone to S5 when the WhatsApp software is already activated?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Every one tells me to activate the WhatsApp account only after the transfer of the file have been done. In my case I have already activated the WhatsApp account.

How can I still transfer the file in?
Thanks

Comment: Raw guess: Delete the app's data (from *Settings › Apps*) and then let it restore from that backup? I'm not using WA, but according to what I've read about that's the way it should work. Also see: [Merging WhatsApp chat histories from different devices but same account](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/107114/16575)